# I want to use result of a query in sql but it has some repetitive value, I want its distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is

```
SELECT 
    [date], [Id], COUNT(*) AS cc
FROM 
    BestReviews
WHERE
    customer = 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'
GROUP BY
    [id], [date]
HAVING 
    COUNT(Id) > 50 
ORDER BY
    cc DESC
```

It returns a result like this:

```
1999-3-22   534215  64
1999-3-22   220009  64
1998-11-18  139545  58
1998-11-18  314112  58
1998-11-18  427338  58
1999-11-16  75564   55
1999-11-16  279232  55
```

and I want just 3 distinct date of this query. e.x. 1999-3-22  and 1998-11-18 and 1999-11-16. in ordered way descendant

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It is suspicious that different `id`s for the same date have the asme count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT  date ,
            id ,
            cc
    FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY date ORDER BY id ) ctr
              FROM      ( SELECT    [date] ,
                                    [Id] ,
                                    COUNT(*) AS cc
                          FROM      BestReviews
                          WHERE     customer = 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'
                          GROUP BY  [id] ,
                                    [date]
                          HAVING    COUNT(Id) > 50
                        ) Main
            ) T
    WHERE   ctr = 1
    ORDER BY cc DESC
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works and give me what exactly I want.

Comment: Welcome! :) Just wanted to reiterate that the suggestion of @Gordon Linoff is correct, you're having a multiple results due to it's different id's if you remove the id from the group by and select, it will give you the same desired result. however, if you want to retain the id.. just remove id from the group by and put max(id) from the select, though I answer above  in a form of sub-query.. the reason behind is to preserve your query result.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear why you would be getting the same count for different ids.

But, the answer to your question appears to be to remove `id` from the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT [date], count(*) as cc
FROM BestReviews
WHERE customer = 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'
GROPU BY [date]
HAVING count(*) > 50 
ORDER BY cc DESC;
```

Comment: but if I delete Id it doesn't work properly. because count of Id is important in group by not count of date.